# how to organize comments with their appropriate replies in php and mysql?

Tags: php, mysql, comments

so, i was trying to make a comment system with php and mysql, so i created these 2 tables

```
table:posts
id      person      post    
1       John Doe    this is the first post.
2       David Adams this is a comment for the first post.
3       Michael     this is the second post.
4       Anonymous   this is another post from abdou.
5       mahmoud     good job
6       Anonymous   is it working right now OHHHH.
7       Abdou       Yep bro you did it congratulations :)
8       khoudir     yeah that is really amazing!

table:comments
c_id    parent_id   post_id     person_comment      comment     
1          0          1            Abdou            nice post
2          1          1            achref           yes indeed
3          0          7            Khoudir          well done abdou good job
4          3          7            Abdou            thank you mr.khousdir
5          4          7            Khoudir          your welcome abderrahmen
6          0          7            achref           good job making this abdou
7          4          7            achref           you did a good job
```

i was able to fetch all the posts with their related comments and replies with this code:

```
                <?php

             include '../post/db.php';
             $sql = "SELECT * FROM posts";
             $prepare = $conn->prepare($sql);
             $prepare->execute();
             while($row = $prepare->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)){
               echo '
               <div>
               <p>post</p>
               <p>'.$row['person'].'</p>
               <p>'.$row['post'].'</p>
               </div>
               <div style="background: #aaa;">
               <p>comments</p>';
               comments_and_replies($row['id']);
               echo '</div>';
            }

            function comments_and_replies($row_id, $margin_left = 0){
              include '../post/db.php';
              $sql = "SELECT * FROM comments WHERE post_id = ?";
              $prepare2 = $conn->prepare($sql);
              $prepare2->execute([$row_id]);
              while($comment = $prepare2->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)){
                if($comment['parent_id'] == 0){
                  $margin_left = 0;
                  echo '
                  <p>'.$comment['person_comment'].'</p>
                  <p>'.$comment['comment'].'</p>
                  ';
                }else{
                  $margin_left = $margin_left + 20;
                  echo '
                  <p style="margin-left: '.$margin_left.'px; color: red;">'.$comment['person_comment'].'</p>
                  <p style="margin-left: '.$margin_left.'px; color: red;">'.$comment['comment'].'</p>
                  ';
                }
              }
            }
```

**and the result was:**

########################

post

John Doe

this is the first post.

comments

Abdou

nice post

```
achref

yes indeed
```

####################################

post

David Adams

this is a comment for the first post.

comments

#######################################

post

Michael

this is the second post.

#######################################

post

Anonymous

this is another post from abdou.

comments

#######################################

post

mahmoud

good job

comments

#######################################

post

Anonymous

is it working right now OHHHH.

comments

#######################################

post

Abdou

Yep bro you did it congratulations :)

comments

Khoudir

well done abdou good job

```
Abdou

thank you mr.khousdir

    Khoudir

    your welcome abderrahmen
```

achref

good job making this abdou

```
achref

you did a good job
```

#######################################

post

khoudir

yeah that is really amazing!

comments

**So the problem i'am facing is with this part:**

comments

Khoudir

well done abdou good job

```
Abdou

thank you mr.khousdir

    Khoudir

    your welcome abderrahmen
```

achref

good job making this abdou

```
achref

you did a good job
```

The last reply where achref says you did a good job is supposed to be a reply to the comment where abdou says thank you mr.khoudir and this comment:

```
achref

good job making this abdou
```

is supposed to be an independent comment.

the parent for this comment:

```
achref

you did a good job
```

is specified in the parent_id column in the comments table which is this comment:

```
    Abdou

    thank you mr.khousdir
```

Despite that, it appears under that independent comment.

**My questions is:**

Can someone please help me solve this problem, and is there a better way to organize the database so that i can select all the posts and under each post it's related comments and under each comment it's related replies.

**i'm sorry if my question is confusing**

Comment: your question is too confusing, i don't get what you wqant to achieve

Comment: i'am sorry for that, i just want to display replies under their appropriate parent

Comment: If you are using mysql 8 you can use `recursive cte ` to get your hierarchical data into a result table